# parsing csv file, populating struct and write binary data file

Tags: c, parsing, csv, struct

I am trying to read csv file and parse it then populate a struct to write into a binary .dat file and I am stuck at the moment. I am trying to create 10 list of .csv file and here is the example of csv file format:
1001, Shannon, Rylie, 5824.12, 1500.00

and here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXBUFSIZE 511
#define LOOPNUMBER 30
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

typedef struct{
int     accountNumber;
char    firstName[MAXBUFSIZE + 1];
char    lastName[MAXBUFSIZE + 1];
double  accountBalance;
double  lastPaymentAmount;
} accounts;

int main(void){

    int i;
    char buf[1024];
    const char* tok;

    accounts myarray[10];

    FILE    *fpData;

accounts temp = { 0, "", "", 0.0, 0.0 };

if ((fpData = fopen("accounts.csv", "r")) == NULL) //Reading a file
{
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
}

while (fgets(buf, BUFFER_SIZE, fpData) != NULL)
{
    /* Here we tokenize our string and scan for " \n" characters */

    // for(tok = strtok(buf,"\n");tok;tok=strtok(NULL,"\n"))
    // {
    tok = strtok(buf, ",");
    temp.accountNumber = atoi(tok);
    printf(" %i ", temp.accountNumber);

    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strncopy(temp.firstName, tok, MAXBUFSIZE);
    temp.firstName[MAXBUFSIZE] = '\0';

    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strncopy(temp.lastName, tok, MAXBUFSIZE);
    temp.lastName[MAXBUFSIZE] = '\0';

    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    temp.accountBalance = atof(tok);
    printf("temp.accountBalance = %.2f ", temp.accountBalance);

    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    temp.lastPaymentAmount = atof(tok);
    printf("temp.lastPaymentAmount = %.2f ", temp.lastPaymentAmount);

    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    printf("\n");

    memcpy(&myarray[LOOPNUMBER], &temp, sizeof(accounts));
}

if ((fpData = fopen("accounts.dat", "wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
}
else
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fwrite(myarray, sizeof(accounts), 10, fpData);
    }
}

fclose(fpData);
}
```

Comment: 1) What is `strncopy()` ?  2) `memcpy(&myarray[LOOPNUMBER], &temp, sizeof(accounts));` is one beyond the allocated size for myarray

Comment: 1) `myarray[LOOPNUMBER]` :  `LOOPNUMBER` --> counter_index (i.e 0..9) 2) `fwrite(myarray, sizeof(accounts), 10, fpData);` --> `fwrite(&myarray[i], sizeof(accounts), 1, fpData);` or not use loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a short answer, you really need to check your code, there's one too many strtoks.

But the main problem is here ...  I've got the snippet and changed the fwrite - please review.

```
if ((fpData = fopen("accounts.dat", "wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
}
else
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fwrite( &myarray[ i ], sizeof(accounts), 1, fpData );
    }
}
```